# Problems to get POST response JavaScript front / node js back

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, post, cors

im trying to connect to my local node server route (http://localhost:3000/user-ragnarok-controller/saveragnarokuser/) from my javascript application and im getting no response from it. The server is receiving the request and is processing the same, but i cant get the response at client side.

my javascript app are running at localhost:80 (Apache XAMPP) and my node server at localhost:3000.

this is my javascript code to connect to node server end-point:

```
function handler() {
    alert('handler');
    if(invocation.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && invocation.status === 200) {
        alert('entrei aqui');
        console.log(invocation.responseText);
    } else 
        alert('nao foi hj ' + invocation.status.toString());
}

function saveUser() {   
    alert('dourado  ');
    var eml = document.getElementById('emailInputRegister');
    var user = document.getElementById('userInputText');
    var sx = document.getElementById("sexInputSelected");
    var selectedSex = sx.options[sx.selectedIndex].value;
    var pwd = document.getElementById("passwordInputRegister");

    var uri = 'http://localhost:3000/user-ragnarok-controller/saveragnarokuser/';
    var body = {
        'userid': user.value,
        'userpass': pwd.value,
        'email': eml.value,
        'sex': selectedSex
    };


    invocation.open('POST', uri);
    invocation.withCredentials = true;
    invocation.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    invocation.onreadystatechange = this.handler;
    invocation.send(JSON.stringify(body));
}
```

this is my request at google chrome console

[image: chrome http]

Now let's talk about the server side. Here i have a middleware for CORS treatment.

```
// Add headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  console.log('reqHeaders: ' + JSON.stringify(req.headers));
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'content-type');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  if(req.method === 'OPTIONS')
    return res.status(200).send({});

  next();
});
```

After CORS, the server starts my route POST:

```
router.post('/saveragnarokuser',function(req,res,next){

    console.log('######################### Iniciando saveragnarokuser.');

    UserRagnarokController.addUser(req.body,function(err,count){
        if(err){
            console.log('entrei aqui error: ' + err);
            res.json(err);
        }
        else{

            console.log('entrei aqui ok');

            var userObj = {
                response: "OK"
             };

            res.status(200).json(userObj);
        }
    });
});
```

looking to the server log its possible to see the request coming, processing, but for some reason the POST response is -- ms --. With no Status and execution time.

```
reqHeaders: {"host":"localhost:3000","connection":"keep-alive","content-length":"88","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36","content-type":"application/json","accept":"*/*","origin":"http://localhost","sec-fetch-site":"same-site","sec-fetch-mode":"cors","sec-fetch-dest":"empty","referer":"http://localhost/co-cadastro/register.html?","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"}
######################### Iniciando saveragnarokuser.
myReqbody: {"userid":"fernandocabeca","userpass":"1234","email":"acosta.aluiz@gmail.com","sex":"F"}
POST /user-ragnarok-controller/saveragnarokuser/ - - ms - -
entrei aqui ok
```

My function UserRagnarokController.addUser performed perfectly, the requisition data was successfully filled in the database, i just need to get this response at client side (google chrome app), i got no error and no success.

NOTE: when I execute the request at POSTMAN it works normally, the answer is 200 OK.[image: POSTMAN TEST]

Comment: Can you click the response tab at the top of the request that's failing? It's in this screenshot next to 'Headers' and 'Preview'. It should have an error message that will tell us what went wrong. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj5BR.png

Comment: @georgedum response for the request blocked by CORS is empty. :)

Comment: @georgedum tab response value is: failed to load response data.

Comment: I imagine your backend is never sending a response. Try putting a console.log statement or debugger one line above your invocation.send()

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a warning in the browser's console about breaking of CORS policy.

Headers about CORS should come from your server (Response Headers) and I don't see that tab here in your screenshot.

[image]

Postman ignores CORS, and server process all request by default.

Comment: Man sorry about that but you could give me a little more details? Im on this problem for hours and i try everything. I need to change my middleware CORS at server side or my request at client side? @Deykun

Comment: `Access-control-allow` etc. should be returned from your node server. You can download an extension called "CORS everywhere" and you probably will be able to see the response in your browser but that because of this extension.

Comment: "I already have these rules written. am I doing it wrong?" - I guess since they do not appear in the response. :)

Sorry, I'm working in the frontend, so I can't help you with express (it looks like express server), I can recognize CORS at front but it is the backend issue. You can try adding `cors` npm to your server: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html